# Are there calculations regarding the Kármán line in the Theodore von Kármán collection?

Tags: history, atmosphere, karman-line, historical-data

According to [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0094576518308221), page 673:

> The "von Kármán line" appears to be what mathematicians refer to as a "folk theorem" , arising out of a conference discussion but never formally published by him. It was fleshed out in later publications, especially in the influential work of [Haley(1963)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_G._Haley) and there is some justification for calling it the "von Kármán-Haley line".

Space lawyer [Andrew G. Hailey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_G._Haley) was a friend of Theodore von Kármán and they worked together for years in the [Aerojet Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerojet).

The [Theodore von Kármán collection](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/25071/1/vonKarmanCollectionGuide.pdf) is a guide to the original collection of papers, personal correspondence, scientific notes, illustrations etc. and there is also a microfiche publication of this collection.

The personal correspondence section of the collection in box 12 also has the correspondence with Andrew Haley and there is a good chance that in some of those letters calculations regarding the altitude of the Kármán line are present.
And in some scientific notes as well of course.

So who would like to visit the [California Institute of Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Institute_of_Technology)  and look for those calculations in the [Theodore von Kármán collection](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/25071/1/vonKarmanCollectionGuide.pdf) ?

Comment: Why not communicate with the librarians there?  I'm sure you can get access... for a price...

Comment: @Paul  I'm living in Europe, maybe we'll get attention with this question from people living near the C.I.T. It would be a real breakthrough if someone discovered those calculations.